# Feature development xPages

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xpages

I have updated my feature before uninstalling it. This made uninstall impossible. After that, deleting everything with my namespace in folder \Data\workspace\applications\eclipse did not help

Now I'm seeing an old feature in File->Application Managment with error saying

> "This feature was not loaded."

And later while building project in site.xml, it threw an error saying

> "Problems during export"

When else needs to be cleaned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found xml config file from which notes reads site.xml's. Found site with my feature. Deleted my feature, saved, started notes and now it works.

Xml config file path:

Data\workspace.config\org.eclipse.update\platform.xml